# Bipartite distance-regular graph with odd diameter: is maximum-distance-relation connected?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, connectedness

consider a distance-regular graph of odd diameter d, and assume it is bipartite but not antipodal.  Is the maximum-distance-relation connected, and if so, is there a quick way to see this?

The book Brouwer-Cohen-Neumaier (Theorem 4.2.1) does state if one of the distance relations (for a distance i in {1,...d}) is disconnected, the graph should be a polygon, bipartite of antipodal, but that's not quite as strong as the statement I'm looking for.